# Any probable cause why my slider is being covered from other blocks (content,sidebar) even it's working behind them?

Tags: slideshow, carousel

I recently add HiSlider im my website.
I am using it at the front page an on 95% page loads the slider is being covered by the blocks of the page (which are supposed to be below,after, the slider).Sometimes on page load everything is working correctly.(I have the slider in an other page too link to a menu.By clicking the menu the slider in this page is working)
Any ideas?

Comment: Are you initialising the slider ondomready? $(function(){  //initialize now });

Answer (score 0):

have a look at the CSS [z-index property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp).

```
#your-hi-slider-id{
    z-index: 99;
}
```

Edit: I see this is not the problem you're having,

Because the page sometimes works, I believe the javascript may be excecuted before the page is ready

```
function init(){
    //initialize your slider here
}

<body onload="init()">
```

Comment: Tried it before but still same results.

Comment: By the way i want the slider above the blocks.Not over the blocks.